# Why are old kernels marked as manually installed?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, kernel

From everything I've read, in Ubuntu 18.04 `sudo apt-get autoremove` should clean up old kernels. However, for some reason, after installing a new kernel version, I am left with "linux-image-*", "linux-headers-*" and "linux-modules-*" packages which are inexplicably marked as manually installed, and therefore are not cleaned up by `apt-get autoremove`.

I have not manually installed these packages (for example `linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic`), and can't figure out what is marking them as manually installed.

Why are these packages getting marked as manually installed? And how can I stop that from happening?

## Update

I'm replying to @user535733 here, because it is too long for a comment. I think this is something different than the script in /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal.

Looking at that script, it doesn't mark the packages as manually installed, instead it writes an apt configuration file with a "APT::NeverAutoRemove" section that lists the kernels that shouldn't be removed. And I understand that. The problem is the packages I'm seeing marked as manually installed *are not* in that list. And they are never removed by `autoremove` even after multiple kernel updates.

And by marked as manually installed, I mean that `apt-mark showmanual linux-*` lists these packages and `apt-mark showauto linux-*` does not.

## Update 2

I found this in my apt history:

```
Remove: linux-headers-5.0.0-32:amd64 (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-32-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2), linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2), linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-70.79), linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-70.79), linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2), gradle-6.0:amd64 (1.0-0ubuntu2), linux-modules-4.15.0-70-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-70.79)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

And the corresponding term.log contains:

```
Log started: 2019-12-21  22:23:02
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
Log ended: 2019-12-21  22:23:02
```

So it looks like autoremove tried and failed to remove the packages. (And I think it is failing because it is in a cron job and the PATH isn't set correctly). I still don't understand how they became marked as manually installed though. I don't see anything else suspicious in the apt history or term.log

Answer (score 1):

The script `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` governs which kernel packages are apt-marked 'manual' (ineligible for autoremoval) and which are apt-marked 'auto' (eligible).

There is a good reason for it: It's very wise to keep at least one old kernel handy in case a new kernel fails to boot.

This is contrary to normal Debian practice of installing only one version of a package at a time. So apt isn't well-equipped to handle this corner-case. Hence the need for the script.

The logic that the script uses is described in the script, and is easy to follow. Take a look at it.

Comment: I updated the question, because a response is too long for a comment

Answer (score -2):

Why you don't use ukuu, you can find how to install ukuu below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Comment: Please explain how this might answer the OPs question.

Comment: ukuu GUI can be used to update and delete old kernels.

Comment: you can install old kernel as well.

Comment: @karel That may very well be true; but, it still does not answer the OPs question as to _why_ previously installed kernels are marked as being "manually installed". Still not an answer.